# TypeError: importPackage is not a function, it is object

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I get the following error when evaluating `JavaScript` using `Rhino`:

`TypeError: importPackage is not a function, it is object`

This function is a [feature of Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java) used to import Java classes for interoperability with Java.

I looked at the relevant Rhino code and found that the importPackage functionality is contained in a class named `ImporterTopLevel` which appears to be loaded in `ScriptRuntime`:

```
public static ScriptableObject initStandardObjects(Context cx,
                                                   ScriptableObject scope,
                                                   boolean sealed)
{
    ScriptableObject s = initSafeStandardObjects(cx, scope, sealed);

    new LazilyLoadedCtor(s, "Packages",
            "org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaTopPackage", sealed, true);
    new LazilyLoadedCtor(s, "getClass",
            "org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaTopPackage", sealed, true);
    new LazilyLoadedCtor(s, "JavaAdapter",
            "org.mozilla.javascript.JavaAdapter", sealed, true);
    new LazilyLoadedCtor(s, "JavaImporter",
            "org.mozilla.javascript.ImporterTopLevel", sealed, true);

    for (String packageName : getTopPackageNames()) {
        new LazilyLoadedCtor(s, packageName,
                "org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaTopPackage", sealed, true);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Because of this, I would expect it to work, but for some reason, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer myself because I think I found a suitable workaround or possibly the correct way to do this. Also, the error message I saw was nowhere to be found using popular search engines, so this could save somebody's neck down the line.

I found an old [message on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.dev.tech.js-engine.rhino/IYjxHNH0ZpM/nTNndpfifIAJ) which eventually led me to the solution. It sounded a bit cryptic to me because I do not have any experience with the engine:

> To use importPackage your root scope must be created with new
> ImporterTopLevel(cx).

After some digging in the code which was using the engine (which I didn't write), I replaced this line

`Scriptable scope = context.initStandardObjects();`

with this one

`Scriptable scope = new ImporterTopLevel(context);`

I still don't fully comprehend why it wouldn't work despite the code in `ScriptRuntime`, but it works now. The error message itself isn't really true, importPackage is simply not known, the message is an artifact of incorrect error handling similar to `if (isFunction()) {"error about function"} else {"error about object"}`.

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted, but it was exactly what I needed.  The samples for embedding Rhino all show using initStandardObjects rather than ImporterTopLevel as the way to get your scope - which means your script can't call importPackage.